# Split tuple of two elements and add to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a list of tuple in python:`[(3, 0), (3, 6), (9, 6), (9, 9), (13, 10), (13, 1), (16, 8), (12, 17), (20, 18), (10, 21), (24, 17), (8, 25), (28, 25), (18, 31), (32, 8), (19, 33), (29, 33), (34, 37), (34, 19), (33, 37), (35, 40), (40, 24), (40, 50), (46, 40), (40, 40), (11, 43), (43, 47), (43, 26), (35, 46), (42, 49), (52, 44), (46, 53), (54, 36), (57, 37), (70, 60), (26, 63), (39, 66), (69, 44)]`

These are only values without any keys and how should I add the tuples to the dataframe?
So for example I have column A and B and the first element in the tuple is a value for column A and the second for column B.

But how can I split the tuple up and add only the left(first) ones to column A and the right(2nd) to the columns?

Answer (score 2):

```
data = [(3, 0), (3, 6), (9, 6), (9, 9), (13, 10), (13, 1), (16, 8), (12, 17), (20, 18), (10, 21), (24, 17), (8, 25), (28, 25), (18, 31), (32, 8), (19, 33), (29, 33), (34, 37), (34, 19), (33, 37), (35, 40), (40, 24), (40, 50), (46, 40), (40, 40), (11, 43), (43, 47), (43, 26), (35, 46), (42, 49), (52, 44), (46, 53), (54, 36), (57, 37), (70, 60), (26, 63), (39, 66), (69, 44)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A", "B"])

output:
    A   B
0   3   0
1   3   6
2   9   6
3   9   9
4   13  10
....
```